# Are there differences between MOG and GMM algorithms? or is it the same ?

Tags: c++, opencv

MOG= Mixture of Gaussian 
GMM= Gaussian mixture Model

I am really confused because i have rough understanding of there basic, and i am just looking for codes to fulfill my assignment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeap, MOG and GMM are the same thing. From [here](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/GMM/GMMGenerator.html):

The most famous statistical mixture consists of the family of Gaussian mixtures. In the literature, they bear the names of:

- GMMs: Gaussian mixture models
- MoGs: Mixtures of Gaussians

Comment: Ok, thanks 
Do you know which one of BGSLibrary algorithms can represent GMM?
because in BGSLibrary there is nothing algorithms called GMM or MOG 
we have there: 
MixtureOfGaussianV1BGS
MixtureOfGaussianV2BGS

Comment: GMM/MOG are background subtraction algorithms. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0) you can see the opencv documentation. I recommend you to use the same as the example: BackgroundSubtractorMOG2